# What do all these mean?

Tags: terminology

Can someone explain what all these mean?
[image]
(Apple's financials taken from google finance)

Comment: What have you found?

Comment: Fundamental (factual) questions require some initial research, **especially when Google exists**.

Comment: watch these two videos and you'll understand: [income statement](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z7C4cz2HkeY&ab_channel=KhanAcademy) and  [balance sheet](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HJWX3l4u68U&t=30s&ab_channel=Edspira)

Comment: (although I disagree about how Khan Academy calculates ROA) (also, I'm not affiliated with either of these YouTube accounts and I receive no financial incentive to link you to them)

Comment: @RonJohn It is okay for us to have basic questions that are on-topic here. [Our tour page](https://money.stackexchange.com/tour) states our mission as: “to build a library of detailed answers to **every** question about money or personal finance.” With more answers to basic questions here, then when people do a Google search, they might land here on our site, which would be a good thing for us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Quarterly financials" refers to financial figures of the company during a 3-month segment of the year.  Publicly-held companies, such as Apple, are required to report these numbers every quarter on a 10-Q or a 10-K form, and the numbers you see here came from that form.

A quick, incomplete definition of each term follows:

**Revenue** refers to how much money was brought into the company from the sales of its products during the quarter.

[**Net income**](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/n/netincome.asp) is how much of the revenue was left after taking into account the cost of everything they sold and the expenses paid.

[**Diluted Earnings Per Share**](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/d/dilutedeps.asp) is found by taking the earnings (net income) and dividing it by the number of shares that exist in the company.

[**Net profit margin**](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/n/net_margin.asp) is how much profit was made from the total revenue, expressed as a percentage.  In the example above, Net Income 28.75B / Revenue 111.44B = 25.8%.

[**Operating income**](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/o/operatingincome.asp) is another way to measure profit.  It is a little higher than the net income because it doesn't include taxes paid or certain other specific types of expenses.

**Cash on hand** is how much cash the company currently owns.

**Net change is cash** is how much the "cash on hand" number went up or down since last quarter.

[**Cost of revenue**](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/c/cost-of-revenue.asp) measures how much it costs to make sales.  It includes the cost of producing products, but also includes things like marketing and sales expenses.